# PHP - Debug stack with timings

Tags: php

Basically... I need to debug stack with timings.

If I use `var_dump(debug_backtrace())` I get a nice list of functions that were called and their specific order (basically the stack).

Is there any way to add the time elapsed from the start of each one? By this I mean a general one, not one that requires me to add microtime in each function.

Answer (score 0):

There are few profilers available:

- [xdebug](https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler)
- [xhprof](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.xhprof.php)
- [blackfire](https://blackfire.io/)
- [z-ray](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server/z-ray)